# Как сделать RecyclerView "прозрачным" для свайпа?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть основной экран (карта), поверх него установлен `RecyclerView`. На данный момент скроллить RecyclerView нельзя, он просто как окошко для информации. Но, когда я начинаю вести по нему, карта, находящаяся под ним, не движется. Как можно сделать так, чтобы она двигалась при начале движения пальца по территории RecyclerView?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос и тело вопроса отличаются, распишите вашу задачу более детально.

Comment: Изменил вопрос.